# Module name not found error either while running python main.py or running test_main.py

Tags: python, pytest

My project structure is

```
project 
   |
   |---------src
   |          |---------__init__.py
   |          |---------main.py
   |          |---------tools
   |                      |
   |                      |------tool_a.py
   |                      
   |                      
   |--------test
   |          |
   |          |---------__init__.py
              |---------test_main.py
```

In main.py I import the `tools_a` module.

```
#main.py
from tools.tool_a import generate_file
```

This works fine when I run this command on `project` root folder.
`$python src/main.py`

but when I run `$pytest` on same `project` root folder, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools'
```

If I change the import from
`from tools.tool_a import generate_file` to `from src.tools.tool_a import generate_file`

then `pytest` runs but `main.py` logs error that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Not sure which is the way to import module so test and main doesn't fail.

Comment: you are probably missing an __init__.py in your tools module?

Comment: Tried to add empty __init__.py under tools but the same error

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

- make sure you have an __init__.py file in `test`, `src` and `tool` directories
- in `test_main.py`, import like this: `from src.tools.tool_a import generate_file`
- in `main.py`, import like this: `from tools.tool_a import generate_file`
- make sure the parent directory of `src` and `test` is the current working directory and run either `python ./src/main.py` or `pytest ./test`