# pytest gives 'Module not found' error even if module exists in path

Tags: python, import, pytest

I'm doing my first project which even has test files written using pytest. The problem is when i run `python -m pytest`, it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`.
which is weird since, pycharm adds project directory to `sys.path`.

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── tests
│   └── testsUtils
│       ├── demo.csv
│       └── test_imageDataset.py
└── utils
    ├── imageDataset.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── trainer.py
    └── Untitled-1.ipynbtrainer.py
```

I do `python -m pytest` in the `.` folder i.e the project folder.

I'm sick of dealing with python imports already, so much so I switched to pycharm from vscode cuz i had similar issues. It is really annoying that this issue occurred again with pytest.

Any help is appreciated,
thanks

Comment: Nothing in the file tree you shared is named utils...

Comment: @kpie hmm hey!! I'm sry, isnt this named utils ? `└── utils`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67508870/11246056